# Can you generate new self names inside a class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributes, local-variables, global

Trying to figure out how to use a function to generate new self named variables inside a class.

I've played around with it in IDLE, and searched online docs. Solution is alluding me.

```
>>> import random

>>> abc = [(map(chr,range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)))+(map(chr,range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)))]

>>> class Test():
        def __init__(self, abc):
            self.a = 0
            self.abc = abc

        def newSelf(self):
            for i in range(2):
                b = random.choice(abc)
                c = random.choice(abc)
                globals()['self.'+b+c] = 0
                #or
                locals()['self.'+b+c] = 0
                print(b+c,0)

>>> example = Test(abc)
>>> example.a
0
>>> example.newSelf() #say it generates
An 0
ze 0
>>> example.An #calling new self variable of example object returns

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#221>", line 1, in <module>
    example.An
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'An'

# I'm hoping for...
>>> example.An
0
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary to store `An` and `ze` (and any other arbitrarily generated pair of characters)?

Comment: In attempting to generate new self identities on the fly when class method is called I think will help in image processing with pygame. Ultimately I'm trying to break down my bulk sprite images. With being broken up into smaller images, some images are in 20-30 range, while others are 100+ per large image. I'd like to attempt name generation on the fly to be more adaptable, while adding the new names into a list so there will be a reference to write in a call system for objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):**

You can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to set the new attribute:

```
>>> class Test():
...     def __init__(self, abc):
...         self.a = 0
...         self.abc = abc
...     def newSelf(self):
...         for i in range(2):
...             b = random.choice(abc)
...             c = random.choice(abc)
...             setattr(self, b+c, 0)
...             print(b+c,0)
```

And the attribute will again be available:

```
>>> example = Test(abc)
>>> example.newSelf()
zM 0
Ja 0
>>> example.zM
0
>>> example.Ja
0
```

**Using [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):**

You can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function to execute a python statement stored in a string. As, you are generating the variable name randomly, you can create the whole python statement in a string, and execute that statement using `exec` like below:

```
>>> class Test():
...     def __init__(self, abc):
...         self.a = 0
...         self.abc = abc
...     def newSelf(self):
...         for i in range(2):
...             b = random.choice(abc)
...             c = random.choice(abc)
...             exec('self.'+b+c+' = 0')
...             print(b+c,0)
```

Here, I have created the new attribute using `exec('self.'+b+c+' = 0')`. Now, after calling this method, the attribute will be available:

```
>>> example = Test(abc)
>>> example.newSelf()
Tw 0
Xt 0
>>> example.Tw
0
>>> example.Xt
0
```